# Moving between sheets without clicking on the tab

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working in Excel on sheet1. I want to go from sheet1 to sheet3 without clicking on the tab, is there  is there to do this by clicking on a cell or is there a shortcut key for that?

Comment: have you looked at Excel's hyperlinks?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It is difficult to understand what you are asking. Please take a minute to [edit] your question to be more clear, to include what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-PageUp and Ctrl-PageDown are the keyboard shortcuts to switch between worksheets.